# Change color of external ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicolor

I have a viewController and a containerView in it. Unfortunately, I am unable to change the color of the child viewController represented in the containerView from the parent class. Changing the background color of the containerView, which is the only thing I am able to reach from my parent viewController, does not change the background color of the referenced child, but only the invisible containerView holding it.

Therefore, I have tested a method where I call a function from within the class of the child from the parent as shown below:

```
@IBAction func changeToRed(sender: viewController) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 80/255, blue: 30/255, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

**This is in the child viewController**

```
otherView().changeToRed(sender: self)
```

**This in the parent viewController**

This technique does not work. I have already tried it with a regular function and with random trial and error in the parent viewController. Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong? Or is there a potentially different technique to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is otherView ?

Comment: That is just some name I used for this example which references the class of the child view.

Comment: Could you specify the various *view controllers* **and** *views*? It's easy to confuse what is a view versus controller. Two lines of code don't cut it. If you can't do that - then please define your view controller **hierarchy** along with the view **hierarchy** so we can duplicate your issue. Thanks.

Comment: I have one viewController (actually more, but they are irrelevant in this case). In this viewController, I have, in the storyboard, put a UIView which I have called a containerView in my question. This UIView obviously has an embedded segue linked to the view in which I want to change the background color from the viewController. Obviously, I have created an IBOutlet to the view, yet this when doing UIView.backgroundcolor does not affect the visible background.

Comment: For those who are downvoting this question, I would enjoy a helpful working solution. If you cannot supply a proper answer, do not take your time to downvote a valid question. Else, please suggest what I need to improve in my asking of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up the container with Storyboard and segue, then you can get the child view controller like this. You put this in your parent view controller, where you also declare the childViewController.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {        
    childViewController = segue.destination
}
```

Comment: As specified in my question, I do not declare the childViewController. It is simply an IBOutlet, which is therefore already predefined. I have tried possibly redefining this value but that should render useless as my doing this manually in the storyboard automatically creates the link to the ContainerView destination.

Comment: Please try my solution. Your outlet is connected to the container, which is not the child view controller. This solution works. I have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would just be to change the child view controller's view's background to transparent (`UIColor.clear`), either in the XIB/Storyboard or programmatically. Then, you can change the background color of the container view directly, as you tried before.

Comment: This sadly does not work. I have tried adding it before the other section as you suggested, yet this does not make a difference. I believe that it is less of an error assigning the color, but rather a mistake of the setup. For example, I have tested my background color change with a button's IBAction, which did work. Thank you for the suggestion nevertheless.